# Retag request: [adverb] -> [adverbs]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-synonyms

It appears that [[adverb]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adverb) does not resolve to [[adverbs]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adverbs). I tried suggesting a tag synonym accordingly, but it turns out that my score in that tag is too low, so I am not allowed to do that (in fact, [nobody is](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/adverbs/topusers)). I am thus requesting the diamond mods to render assistance. Thanks.

Comment: Seems to be done.